# Perl output format

Tags: perl

I'm reading a log file and grouping it based on the 'Program' name and in turn its ID.

LOG FILE

```
------------------------------------------
DEV: COM-1258
Program:Testing
Reviewer:Jackie
Description:New Entries
rev:r145201
------------------------------------------
QA: COM-9696
Program:Testing
Reviewer:Poikla
Description:Some random changes
rev:r112356
------------------------------------------
JIRA: COM-1234
Program:Development
Reviewer:John Wick
Description:Genral fix
rev:r345676
------------------------------------------
JIRA:COM-1234
Program:Development
Reviewer:None
Description:Updating Received
rev:r909276
------------------------------------------
JIRA: COM-6789
Program:Testing
Reviewer:Balise Mat
Description:Audited
rev:r876391
------------------------------------------
JIRA: COM-8585
Program:Testing
Reviewer:Gold frt
Description: yet to be reviewed
rev:r565639
```

The code I have,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse    = 1;

my $file = "log.txt";
open FH, $file or die "Couldn't open file: [$!]\n";

my $data = {};
my $hash = {};
while (<FH>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ m/(-){2,}/)
    {
        my $program = $hash->{Program} || '';
        my $jira    = $hash->{JIRA} || $hash->{QA} || $hash->{DEV} ||
+'';
        if ($program && $jira)
        {
            push @{$data->{$program}{$jira}}, $hash;
            $hash = {};
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($line =~ m/:/)
        {
            my ($key, $value) = split /:\s*/, $line;
            $hash->{$key} = $value;
        }
        elsif ($line =~ m#/# && exists $hash->{Files})
        {
            $hash->{Files} .= "\n$line";
        }
    }
}
print 'data = ' . Dumper($data);

foreach my $prg (sort keys %{$data})
{
    print "===========================================================
+=\n";
    print "    PROGRAM : $prg
+         \n";
    print "===========================================================
+=\n";

    foreach my $jira (sort keys %{$data->{$prg}})
    {
        print "******************\n";
        print "JIRA ID : $jira\n";
        print "******************\n";

        foreach my $hash (@{$data->{$prg}{$jira}})
        {
            foreach my $key (keys %{$hash})
            {
                # print the data except Program and JIRA
                next if $key =~ m/(Program|JIRA|DEV|QA)/;
                print "    $key => $hash->{$key}\n";
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I have a requirement to print the output in the **below format** and currently unable to do so with my logic, any ideas would be really helpful.

```
PROGRAM:  Development
Change IDs:
1.JIRA
    a.COM-1234

PROGRAM:  Testing
Change IDs:
1.JIRA
    a.COM-6789
    b.COM-8585
2.QA
    a.COM-9696
3.DEV
    a.COM-1258
```

Comment: Are JIRA, DEV & QA fixed?

Comment: @AbhiNickz : Firstly thanks and Yes, they are fixed.

Comment: You mean someone wrote the original code for you and you have no idea how to modify it?

Comment: @Borodin : This is the pre-exisiting script in system and I'm trying to modify according to my requirement as displayed above . I'm kind of new to Perl so struggling to get the exact logic

Comment: @Goku So you mean you haven't tried anything by yourself, but want someone to to the job for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'uniq';

my $file = 'log.txt';
open my $fh, $file or die "Couldn't open file: [$!]\n";

my @data;
{
    my %item;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;

        if ( eof or /\-{2,}/ ) {
            push @data, { %item } if keys %item;
            %item = ();
        }
        else {
            my ( $key, $value ) = split /\s*:\s*/;
            next unless $value;
            $item{$key} = $value;
            $item{jira} = $key if grep { $key eq $_ } qw/ JIRA DEV QA /;
        }
    }
}

my %data;
{
    for my $item ( @data ) {
        my ($prog, $jira) = @{$item}{qw/ Program jira /};
        push @{ $data{$prog}{$jira} }, $item->{$jira};
    }
}

for my $prog ( sort keys %data ) {

    printf "PROGRAM:   %s\n", $prog;
    print "Change IDs:\n";

    my $n = 1;
    for my $jira ( qw/ JIRA QA DEV / ) {

        next unless my $codes = $data{$prog}{$jira};

        printf "%d.%s\n", $n++, $jira;

        my $l = 'a';
        printf "    %s.%s\n", $l++, $_ for sort(uniq(@$codes));
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
PROGRAM:   Development
Change IDs:
1.JIRA
    a.COM-1234

PROGRAM:   Testing
Change IDs:
1.JIRA
    a.COM-6789
    b.COM-8585
2.QA
    a.COM-9696
3.DEV
    a.COM-1258
```

Comment: Really appreciate your inputs here and for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'test';
my $hash;
my $id_hash = ();
my $line_found = 0;
my $line_count = 1;
my $ID;
my $ID_num;

open (my $FH, '<', "$file") or warn $!;

while (my $line = <$FH> ) {

    chomp($line);

    if ( $line =~ m/------------------------------------------/){
        $line_found = 1;
        $line_count++;
        next;
    }

    if ( $line_found ) {
        $line =~ m/(.*?):(.*)/;
        $ID = $1;
        $ID_num = $2;
        $line_found = 0;
    }

    if ( $line =~ m/Program:(.*)/ ) {
        my $pro = $1;
        push @{$hash->{$pro}->{$ID}}, ($ID_num) ;
    }

    $line_count++;
}

close $FH;

foreach my $pro (keys %$hash){
    # print Dumper($pro);

    print "PROGRAM:\t$pro\nChange IDs:\n";

    foreach my $ids (keys $hash->{$pro}){

        print "\t1. $ids\n";

        foreach my $id (values $hash->{$pro}->{$ids}){
            print "\t\ta. $id\n";
        }
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
PROGRAM:        Testing
Change IDs:
        1. QA
                a.  COM-9696
        1. DEV
                a.  COM-1258
        1. JIRA
                a.  COM-6789
                a.  COM-8585
PROGRAM:        Development
Change IDs:
        1. JIRA
                a. COM-1234
                a. COM-1234
```

Just change the output to your need!!

Comment: That's a poor example of Perl. Apart from anything else, it uses `keys` and `values` on hard references, which wasn't possible until Perl v5.14 and has been made illegal in v5.24. That means it will only work on five different releases of Perl, and will probably generating a warnings even on those.